# Export Excel file to Google Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-api

**Hi guys,**

I'm trying to push data from an excel file to a google spreadsheet, using VBA

User Story : When my user close excel, it automatically pushes the data into a back up on google sheet.

I've read some solutions about the Google API, but i do not understand how to use it.

if someone has an explanation it would be nice

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: If the sheet has only one user, you might want to use google drive sync
https://www.google.com/intl/en-GB_ALL/drive/download/backup-and-sync/

Answer (score 0):

Mixing Excel and Google is going to be a tough journey.  They have a lot of compatible features and implementations and then a whole bunch of things that are just not compatible.

You won't be able to control what your users do in Excel so the "backup" may end up as a poor representation of the excel version.

If it is purely for backup, you could go the MSFT route and use OneDrive/O365 which keeps versions for you if you store in a local OneDrive.  You can use auto save to keep your backup up to date.

You could go the google route by using sheets on the desktop browser.

As Thomas suggested, go with an off the shelf sync tool if the data and format is straight forward.  I have had very mixed results for even some simple stuff.

Not wishing to start a tech-religion war by recommending one over the other but how you are trying to achieve this feels fraught with risk and may be hard to future-proof.

HTH.